# MWF GE smartfilter refrigerator water filter needs to be replaced monthly? (instead of 6 months)

Tags: water, filter

We have had an ongoing issue with the MWF water filter needing to be replaced on an almost monthly basis. GE said the issue was with buying the generic brand, so we purchased directly from GE - same exact problem.
Works great for a few weeks then the water slows to a trickle.
Per GE the filter should be replaced every 6 months. 
There is no problem with the water line, as it runs fine without the filter in place. 
Our water is fine (tested by the city - no issues) and we don't use an excessive amount.
Anyone else run into this problem? 
Replacing the filter every month is a huge expense.

Comment: "Our water is fine"  what is "fine" is relative.  Filters plug up for two reasons, they are filtering fine particles that plug it up, or they're cheap quality filters.   Talk to your neighbors do they have this issue?

Comment: Was the water tested by the city from your tap or from elsewhere?

Comment: You could have a pressure issue. Check the water pressure at the inlet to the fridge both static and with flow. If the pressure is below the design criteria this can also cause the same problem.

Comment: Even though it "works great" for a few weeks, you may have low pressure that becomes problematic when the filter is only slightly blocked.  Some fridges come with a filter bypass cartridge.  It's a fake plastic filter that lets you consume unfiltered water.  If you have one, compare the flow, with it, to the flow with a new filter.  With a new filter, after flushing the air out of it, the flow should be indiscernible from the flow with the bypass cartridge.  If the new filter reduces flow, you may have inadequate pressure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Anyone else run into this problem?" isn't the type of question that's answered here and is irrelevant in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, something is plugging up your filter, as replacing the filter (temporarily) fixes the problem. And, just as clearly, it isn't something unusual about the specific filter.

Almost certainly, the problem is with your water: something in it is plugging up the filter. The obvious culprit would be fine particulates that gum up the pores in the filter far faster than expected.

If you disassemble a failed filter you'll probably find the filter media clogged with a fine, probably brown material. Another test would be to fill a glass of water and let it sit overnight; if there's sediment on the bottom in the morning then bingo: you have particulates in your water.

What do you do? Well, you could buy an external water filter system, e.g. something meant to be mounted under a sink, and have it filter everything going into the fridge. That way you can have a much higher-capacity filter, your in-fridge filter will last much longer, and (as it won't be proprietary) the system as a whole should be much cheaper.